# Child-Parent relation between Swing Containers and Components

Tags: java, swing, parent-child, jcomponent

Imagine I have `JPanel` and `JLabel` and I need to check whether `JLabel` has child-parent relation with specific `JPanel`. However, JLabel might be not direct child, but grand-child and so on.

**Is there easy function API to check that which I am missing?**

Of course, I can call `Container.getComponents()` or `Component.getParent()` recursively  and check. Is there easy solution?

Comment: You can simply walk up the component hierarchy from the labels parent until you reach null or you find the component. The method your looking for is getParent

Comment: Yes, I know about `getParent()`. So this would be the easiest solution, right?

Comment: use SwingUtilities windows for component, parent or ancesor ???, hurry & lazy to check API :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, @MadProgrammer, I have tried `isDescendingFrom` from SwingUtilities. I wonder about what happens if there is `JScrollPane` on the way, since added Components are added to `JViewPort`. Should it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Container.isAncestorOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#isAncestorOf%28java.awt.Component%29) (which JComponent inherits) will do what you want.